# Strength of OH bond

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

This question might seem a little general, but how can we know the strength of the OH bond of third period element hydroxides? Does it increase across the period or does it decrease?But more importantly, on what should we rely in order to understand how the strength of the bond changes?